# Detect OS and redirect to mobile app installed

Tags: javascript, android, ios

I have attached below the mobile app button click, Its perfectly working for Android device, only getting an error: safari cannot open the page because the address is invalid, before being redirected to the redirect URL, can you please anyone help me to resolve the issue

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myHref() {
        if (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i))) {
            document.location = 'app://url2';
            setTimeout(function () {
                if (confirm('You do not seem to have the app installed. Do you want to go download it now?')) {
                    location.href = "https://apps.apple.com/";
                }
            }, 300);

        }

        if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)) {
            location.href = "https://play.google.com"
        }
    }
</script>



<a href="#" onclick="myHref()">GET</a>
```

Website: https://wmiserver.com/dosa-hut

Comment: Why not use a [Smart Banner](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html) on iOS?

Comment: hi @Paulw11 actually i need one download link which should be changed as per the OS you can go through the website link on mobile, for example, an android user redirect to the android app store and IOS user apple APP store